# Virtual Machines vs Containers

Tags: containers, virtual-machine, computer-science

Good day to all,

I am currently a student studying computer science and came across the topic on Virtual Machines vs Containers. I have also spent the last 3-4 hours trying to understand Containers. I am able to see the advantages and disadvantages.

However I am not clear, even after hours of research whether Containers acts like VMs. I have configured VMs through VMware in my school where you can initialise different OS in your computer, virtually. The set up takes long though, however for Containers, are you able to have the same interface as VMs? Does it do what VMs do?

Thank you in advance for your help guys.

Comment: Docker's website covers this topic: [Comparing Containers and Virtual Machines](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container)

Answer (score 0):

Well according to GCP:
Containers are lightweight packages of your application code together with dependencies such as specific versions of programming language runtimes and libraries required to run your software services.

Differences with a VM:

-Containers are much more lightweight than VMs
-Containers virtualize at the OS level while VMs virtualize at the hardware level
-Containers share the OS kernel and use a fraction of the memory VMs require

if you want to know more about containers, this links maybe can be useful:

-https://cloud.google.com/learn/what-are-containers

-https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/#container-images

And this other maybe help you to understand better the differences between a VM and a Container:

-https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers